# Find the vector equation of the line through two points

Tags: geometry

Let be the first point $A=(1,2,1)$ and the second point $B=(2,1,1)$. I have to find the vectorial equation of the line through these points.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec{a}=\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{b}=\vec{OB}$. Then the direction vector of the line is
$\vec{a}-\vec{b}$. Hence the vector to an arbitrary point on the line is
$$ \vec{r}=\vec{a}+\lambda (\vec{a}-\vec{b})\quad \lambda \in {\mathbb R}. $$

$$ \vec{a}=\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 2\\ 1\end{array}\right], \quad \vec{b}=\left[\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 1\\ 1\end{array}\right], \quad \vec{a}-\vec{b}=\left[\begin{array}{c} -1 \\ 1\\ 0\end{array}\right]. $$
$$ \vec{r}=\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 2\\ 1\end{array}\right]+\lambda \left[\begin{array}{c} -1 \\ 1\\ 0\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c} 1-\lambda \\ 2+\lambda\\ 1\end{array}\right]\quad (\lambda \in {\mathbb R}). $$

Comment: could you please give me the result? because I'm in trouble how to calculate the direction vector.

Comment: Can it be written as $r:(x,y,z)=(1,2,1)+\lambda(-1,1,0)$?

Comment: Yes, can be. Depends which notation is used by your teacher.

Comment: Personally, I think that if we're going to use $\vec a$ as the fixed point on the line, it's more natural then to take the direction vector to be $\vec b - \vec a$, but obviously it's a personal preference.